# How to construct components from build of materials

Tags: prolog

I have the following predicates that models a PC. What I want is to print all pc compoments and sub-compoments.

I want to do something like this

```
find_set_of_attributes(X):-
 print(X)
 print(X[power)
 print(X[power][usb])

pc([power).
power([usb, voltageregulator]).
usb([container, usbhead, pins]).
voltageregulator([barreljack, capacitor, regulator, leds]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to describe the computer components and sub-components is to use Definite Clause Grammars (DCGs). For example:

```
computer --> monitor, cpu, keyboard, mouse.
...

power --> usb, voltageregulator.

usb --> container, usbhead, pins.

voltageregulator --> barreljack, capacitor, regulator, leds.
```

Components without sub-components can be defined as:

```
capacitor --> [capacitor].
leds --> [leds].
```

To list all the parts (e.g for printing), you can then simply use the de facto standard `phrase/2` predicate. For example:

```
| ?- phrase(computer, Parts).
```

Comment: Interesting use of DCG. Never saw them used for that.

Comment: @GuyCoder You have an example in the Amzi! Prolog documentation. I have a Logtalk version of that example available at https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/blob/master/examples/dcgs/bom.lgt

Comment: Of interest: Amzi [Build of Material](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_dcg.htm#DCGBillMaterials)